play store release Error This release will cause a significant drop in the number of devices your apps supports
I am getting this error while trying to release my Maui Android App build on Google play store = "This release will cause a significant drop in the number of devices your apps supports on the following form factors"

I tried Updating API version : android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33"
But nothing worked

As mentioned in the release notes, Android now just builds 64-bit architectures by default.
If you still want to support the other architectures too (and thus not lose a number of supported devices) you can reenable 32-bits architectures again by adding this to your csproj file:
<RuntimeIdentifiers Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">android-arm;android-arm64;android-x86;android-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>

